# Как научить консоль выводить русские символы в VS Code?

Tags: java, консоль, кодировка, visual-studio-code, powershell

Вот кусок кода, который должен выводить в консоль сообщения на русском:

```java
public static void menu() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    setDebugMode(false);

    try {
        switch (state) {
            case 1:
                println("_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________");
               println(" ");
               println("Это программа создана для блаблабла, ");
               println("а также высчитывания блаблабла.");
               println("_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________");
               println(" ");
    
               state++;
```

Я запускаю уже собранный `jar` файл с помощью `.bat` файла:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 > nul
powershell -Command java -jar platecalcuator-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
pause
```

Вот что выводит консоль:

```
Active code page: 65001
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Р­С‚Рѕ РїСЂРѕРіСЂР°РјРјР° РґР»СЏ РІС‹СЃС‡РёС‚С‹РІР°РЅРёСЏ РєРѕР»РёС‡РµСЃС‚РІР° РїРѕР»СѓС‡Р°РµРјС‹С… РїР»Р°СЃС‚РёРЅ РЅСѓР¶РЅРѕРіРѕ СЂР°Р·РјРµСЂР° РёР· Р»РёСЃС‚РѕРІ Р±РѕР»СЊС€РµРіРѕ СЂР°Р·РјРµСЂР°,
Р° С‚Р°РєР¶Рµ РІС‹СЃС‡РёС‚С‹РІР°РЅРёСЏ СЃРµР±РµСЃС‚РѕР№РјРѕСЃС‚Рё СЌС‚РёС… СЃР°РјС‹С… РїР»Р°СЃС‚РёРЅ Рё РїСЂРёР±С‹Р»Рё.
    _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Р”РѕСЃС‚СѓРїРЅС‹Рµ РєРѕРјР°РЅРґС‹:
 -  DELETE (РІРІРµРґРёС‚Рµ С‡С‚РѕР±С‹ СѓРґР°Р»РёС‚СЊ РїСЂРµСЃРµС‚)
 -  DELETEALL (РІРІРµРґРёС‚Рµ С‡С‚РѕР±С‹ СѓРґР°Р»РёС‚СЊ РІСЃРµ РїСЂРµСЃРµС‚С‹)
 -  DEBUG (РґР»СЏ СЂР°Р·СЂР°Р±РѕС‚С‡РёРєРѕРІ)
 -  -00 (РџСЂРµСЂС‹РІР°РµС‚ РїСЂРѕРіСЂР°РјРјСѓ, РґРѕСЃС‚СѓРїРЅР° Р’Р•Р—Р”Р•, СѓРґР°Р»СЏРµС‚ С‚РµРєСѓС‰РёР№ РїСЂРµСЃРµС‚ РІРѕ РІСЂРµРјСЏ СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅРёСЏ.)
 -  Р�СЃРїРѕР»СЊР·СѓР№С‚Рµ -00 РµСЃР»Рё РЅСѓР¶РЅРѕ РѕС‚РјРµРЅРёС‚СЊ СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅРёРµ РїСЂРµСЃРµС‚Р°.
 -  РќРµ СЂРµРєРѕРјРµРЅРґСѓРµС‚СЃСЏ РёСЃРїРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚СЊ РІ РёРЅРѕРј СЃР»СѓС‡Р°Рµ.

РќР°Р¶РјРёС‚Рµ 'Enter' С‡С‚РѕР±С‹ РїСЂРѕРґРѕР»Р¶РёС‚СЊ
```

`.bat` сохранен в `utf-8`, и в VS Code терминал успешно выводит кириллицу.

Шрифт consolas

Answer (score 0):

Для этого откройте командную строку (cmd) от имени администратора, введите команду chcp 1251 и нажмите Enter.
Затем переключите кодовую страницу на CP866 командой chtty 866 и проверьте, появился ли русский язык в консоли.

Comment: не помогло.....

Comment: Убедитесь, что в свойствах проекта выбран правильный шрифт с поддержкой кириллицы. На Windows это может быть Consolas, Terminal или Lucida Console.

Answer (score 0):

добавьте в main setlocale(LC_CTYPE "");

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Я просто добавил `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"));`
перед использованием `System.Out.print`

Обработайте его в блоке `try-catch`.